# ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: angular, typescript

I just migrated my project under angular-cli and I'm getting this error when I start it:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or
>   lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 63:45 in the
>   original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in
>   C:/Data/Private/Innovation/EV/ev-dashboard/src/app/app.module.ts

Which corresponds to the APP_INITIALIZER below in app.module.ts:

```
...
providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
    APP_PROVIDERS,
    ConfigService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => () => config.load(), deps: [ConfigService], multi: true }
...
```

What is funny is that when I comment this line, it starts well and uncomment it afterward which triggers a compilation without error this time!!!

Do you have an idea?

Thanks,
Serge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract function like:

```
export function configFactory(config: ConfigService) {
  return () => config.load()
}

...
providers: [{ 
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
  useFactory: configFactory, 
  deps: [ConfigService], 
  multi: true 
}
```

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262
- [Angular4 APP_INITIALIZER won't delay initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639136/angular4-app-initializer-wont-delay-initialization)