# ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ɵmakeDecorator'

Tags: angular, typescript

Related to [ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694392/error-in-error-encountered-resolving-symbol-values-statically)

Further reference: [1](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4647) [2](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3707) [3](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4122) [4](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5015) [5](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262)

I am currently building a [TypeScript library](https://github.com/zurfyx/angular-contents) for Angular (using Angular 4). After enabling [AOT](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#compile-with-aot), I am getting this error.

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling
>   function 'ɵmakeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider
>   replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported
>   function,  resolving symbol NgModule in
>   /home/.../node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol
>   MyModule in /home/.../dist/contents.module.d.ts, resolving symbol
>   MyModule in /home/.../dist/contents.module.d.ts

Depending on the Angular version I get this other error instead:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling
>   function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported[...]

[Enabling AOT](https://github.com/zurfyx/angular-contents/commit/ef1693aae7fa8af7e8e68b61fe010378bf54148c) on the Angular project prevented this:

> ERROR in MyModule is not an NgModule

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### A better solution:

Force your Angular project (or angular-cli) to load your `@angular` dependencies from your main project, not the library's one.

**tsconfig.json** *(remember that angular-cli main tsconfig files remain in src/tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json)*

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "paths": { "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"] }
}
```

Credits to [SebastianSchenk](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3854#issuecomment-274344771) and [drew-moore](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3854#issuecomment-299109237).

---

### Previous attempt:

After a few hours testing and digging through GitHub issue responses...

I found out it was as simple as **not** having a `node_modules/` folder inside the client's installation. [That](https://github.com/zurfyx/angular-contents) is the library I was working on (click [here](https://github.com/zurfyx/angular-contents/tree/a8918209600876238e16f18dcfc6d3dbf6c35c25) to go up until the commit it was working OK).

Hence, you might have `node_modules` whilst working in your development setup, but as soon as you integrate your project into another one remove that folder.

In my case, the reason we I was having a node_modules folder inside the client's folder was due to a previous `npm link` -> `npm link my-package`. Since I was working with `node_modules` on my development setup they were on the linked folder as well.

---

Note that your issue might as well come from somewhere else:

For example: beware of lambdas, use function instead.

and a lot more:

- const lambda => export function
- default export => named export
  *private, protected accessors should be changed to public for any members accessed from template
- dynamic component template => static template
- moduleId should be set on components with templateUrl

make sure to check the [full description of each of these](https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5) — credits to [Isaac Mann](https://medium.com/@isaacplmann).

Comment: Thanks. Been looking at Github for the past hour and didn't find this info (it's a maze!). Hopefully the problem will be fixed by Microsoft since I imagine it's a very common problem for most people working in teams and doing library developments.