# Use Service response to load config in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-module

```
@NgModule({
    declaration: [...],   
    imports: [.., HeaderModule.forRoot({headerConfig: myHeaderConfig, ...})],
    providers: [...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

This is how my app.module file is looking. I have to call a service to load myHeaderConfig values but till the time I receive service response, bootstraping of app is done without any header config. Is there any way to bootstrap app after a service call or any other idea? Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the APP_INITIALIZER construct to bootstrap your module. Look at my answer at [Pass web application context to Angular2 Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567158/pass-web-application-context-to-angular2-service/40567677#40567677)